# How to promote in GitLab from dev to staging?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

In Heroku I can set up dev > staging > prod pipeline, and i.e. when tester says it is ready to get to staging, he moves commit from dev to staing with pressing "Promote". Is it available in GitLab?

So withouth touching git, just move a branch forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the pipeline up in full with deployment to each environment, but set the release to require manual intervention using [when](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when)

e.g.

```
deploy to dev
  stage: dev_test
  script:
    - deploy...
  when: manual

deploy to staging
  stage: staging_release
  script:
    - deploy...
  needs: 
    - deploy to dev
  when: manual
```

The deployment will need to be manually triggered from the pipeline screen before it will take place